# Chrome ignores CSS when iframe is scaled

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The code when run works fine in Firefox but when in Chrome- it doesn't work at all- the #agree element from iframe cannot be hidden. How to fix it for Chrome?

Here's my simplified code:

```
<iframe src="blank.htm"></iframe>

<button id="btn">Toggle</button>

<script>
frame = null;

$('iframe').load(function()
{
    frame = $('iframe').contents();
});

$('#btn').click(function()
{
    var div = frame.find('#agree');
    div.toggle();
});
</script>

<style>
iframe
{
    width: 600px;
    height: 1200px;
    transform: scale(0.5);
}
</style>
```

And here you can test it:
http://nitton.pl/chrome/

Comment: Try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe?rq=1

Comment: @ShaunLoftin If I remove transform: scale(0.5); from my style then it all works fine in Chrome and Firefox. Seems Chrome has a serious bug.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between chrome and firefox is that **chrome uses `-webkit-transform:` browser engine and firefox doesn't.**

Try using the webkit to make it work optimally on chrome browsers.

Comment: That doesn't help here.

Comment: How so? If chrome is the only problem then that should be work.

Comment: Chrome already does understand "transform" without "-webkit-" prefix. The problem is that it didn't refresh changes.